# wp_insert_user email confirmation

Tags: comments, wp-mail

I'm creating a new user once they leave a comment, i am doing this with wp_insert_user

function create_comment_user($comment_ID){
    global $wpdb;

```
$comment = get_comment($comment_ID, ARRAY_A);
if($comment["user_id"] == 0){
    $user = get_user_by('email', $comment["comment_author_email"]);
    if(! $user){
        $new_id = wp_insert_user(array(
                'user_pass' => wp_generate_password(),
                'user_login' => $comment["comment_author_email"],
                'user_email' => $comment["comment_author_email"],
                'user_nicename' => strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $_POST['author'])).'-'.strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $_POST['author_last'])),
                'display_name' => ($_POST['author']).' '.($_POST['author_last']),
                'first_name' => ($_POST['author']),
                'last_name' => ($_POST['author_last']),
                'role'      => 'Subscriber'
            )
        );
        if($new_id)
            wp_new_user_notification( $new_id );
    }
}
return;
}
add_action("comment_post", "create_comment_user", 10, 1);
```

The email confirmation does not get sent, but the user is being created. Any ideas why?

Comment: Did you check if the user is created? `$new_id` can also be a `WP_Error` object, which evaluates to true in your condition

Comment: $new_id is returning an int referring to a new user, so this part seems to work..

Comment: Found the problem, was a silly mistake in my wp_new_user_notifcation that was returning before the mail was sent. Please delete this question